# Cocoa Bindings in the face of a million of items in an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings

I'm writing a GUI for MongoDB using Cocoa. It's going well, but I don't know how to make KVO properties that would be lazily loaded. How does one handle that?

For instance, viewing the documents in a Mongo collection. The collection might have a million items in it. I suspect I shouldn't be downloading the full 2-5 GiB of data to my Cocoa app, then format and display 20 rows. How does one implement that?

I called my project [Mongo Explorer](http://github.com/francois/mongo_explorer/tree/2faf81cc25d7dc92b5399b8e21ef70ab10163ad7), available on GitHub. Specifically, how would I code [-[MECollection reload]](http://github.com/francois/mongo_explorer/blob/2faf81cc25d7dc92b5399b8e21ef70ab10163ad7/MECollection.m#L39) to be lazy? Do I need to implement a data source delegate for my NSTableView?

Comment: Silly nitpick, but Objective-C convention would be to use `-[MECollection reload]` instead of `MECollection#reload`.

Comment: I wasn't sure which was the convention. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manage lazy loading either in an `NSArrayController` subclass or by implementing the `NSTableView` data source delegate. The former is more general (you could use it for other view types), but the later is probably easier.

Comment: I'll go with the data source delegate. As you said, it's much easier.